# Necessary condition for existence of anti-derivative

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is analytic on the domain $D = \{z \big| |z|>1\}$ in $\mathbb{C}$.   I know that if the line integral of $f$ along any closed path is 0 then $f$ has an anti-derivative.  Is this also a necessary condition.

Comment: How would you compute the line integral if you knew that, say, $F(z)$ were an anti-derivative?

Comment: I'm rather confused by your statement. For any analytic function $f$, by the [Cauchy-Goursat theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy-Goursat_theorem), its integral along any closed path is 0. Are you sure you are correctly stating what you want?

Comment: The domain I am looking at is not simply connected so I dont believe Cauchy-Goursat applies.

Comment: Oh, oops, read the inequality the other way. You really shouldn't use $D$ for a domain that is not a disk :p (Though steps used in the *proof* of Cauchy-Goursat will also give you what you want, like Jonas' answer below.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  If $F'=f$ and $\gamma:[a,b]\to D$ is a curve, then $\int_\gamma f = F(\gamma(b))-F(\gamma(a))$.  For example, see Theorem 1.18 on [page 65](http://books.google.com/books?id=9LtfZr1snG0C&lpg=PP1&ots=OePFw5q3Ex&dq=conway%20complex&pg=PA65#v=onepage&q&f=false) of John B. Conway's *Functions of one complex variable*.